# Ajax calling jSON receiving undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the below `ajax` calling a `json` file to display in an HTML table. Initially it worked but is now returning `UNDEFINED`.

Is it possible that the `json` file hasn't finished loading before the script continues on?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var displayUsers = $('#stage');

    displayUsers.text('Retreiving users...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "users.json",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            var output = "<table id='user-table' class='table table-hover'><thead><tr><th onclick='sortTable(0)' class='main-header' data-is-only-head='false' style='text-align: left;'>ID</th><th onclick='sortTable(1)' class='main-header' data-is-only-head='false' style='text-align: left;'>Name</th><th onclick='sortTable(2)' class='main-header' data-is-only-head='false' style='text-align: left;'>HighFives</th><th onclick='sortTable(3)' class='main-header' data-is-only-head='false' style='text-align: left;'>Excluded</th></thead><tbody>";
            for (var i in result) {
                output += "<tr><td>" + result[i].id + "</td><td>" + result[i].name + "</td><td>" + result[i].reward + "</td><td>" + result[i].excluded + "</td></tr>";
            }
            output += "</tbody></table>";

            displayUsers.html(output);
            $("table").addClass("table");
        }
    });
});
```

Sample of json file:

```
{"id":"U123456","gift":0,"reward":0,"name":"joe.smith","excluded":true}
```

Comment: `Is it possible that the json file hasn't finished loading before the script continues on?` No as the `success` handler function only fires after a response is received. I'd suggest checking the console for errors.

Comment: Also note that you have a lot of HTML in your JS code which is not optimal as it ties the JS and UI code too tightly. I'd suggest using a template of some kind instead.

Comment: There must be some undefined value that is turning the whole variable into undefined. Check all values, row by row. You should be able to figure it out

Comment: Try posting your `json` file without exposing any sensitive information. It will be easier to solve this problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll try to limit the amount of HTML that is being parsed in the script and use appends instead. The console doesn't see any errors. It shows the full json contents that are being pulled. Here is a sample of the users.json file:

    {"id":"U123456","gift":0,"reward":0,"name":"joe.smith","excluded":true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you provided doesn't match the code; your code should look like the following based on the snippet you provided:

```
output += "<tr><td>" + result.id + 
           "</td><td>" + result.name + 
           "</td><td>" + result.reward + 
           "</td><td>" + result.excluded + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Ahhhh!!! I thought the script needed the `[i]` since it was set in the `var i in result`

Thanks everyone!!!!

Comment: This resolves the `UNDEFINED` errors but removing the `[i]` now repeats the output four times.

Comment: Your data structure doesn't match the code as the @Brian Mains provided in the answer. If it's a simple structure like this `{"id":"U123456","gift":0,"reward":0,"name":"joe.smith","excluded":true}`, remove the `for (var i in result)`